# Delphi Form closing by Close button on caption bar using Timer

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a project with one FadeIn Timer and One FadeOut Timer. My form is created by FadeIn Timer and is closed by FadeOut Timer. Initially FadeIn Timer is enabled and FadeOut Timer is disabled. FadeIn Timer Code :

```
if MainForm.AlphaBlendValue >= 235 then
  Timer01.Enabled := false 
else 
  MainForm.AlphaBlendValue := MainForm.AlphaBlendValue + 5;
```

FadeOut Timer Code :

```
if MainForm.AlphaBlendValue <= 0 then 
  Timer02.Enabled := false 
else 
  MainForm.AlphaBlendValue := MainForm.AlphaBlendValue - 5; 
close;
```

My requirement is that the FadeOut Timer will be active if I click on the "X" Button of the Caption Bar. So I defined

```
if Msg.Result=htClose then 
  FadeOutTimer.Enabled:=true;
```

But it not working. Please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the form just closes immediately, then you need a global form variable like `FAllowClose` that you set to `False` when the form is created.  Then you need to write code for the `Form.CloseQuery` event.  Something simple like this should work:

```
procedure Form.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if FAllowClose then
    Exit;

  CanClose := False;
  FadeOut.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure Form.FadeOutOnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // do fade out
  FAllowClose := True;
  Self.Close
end;
```

<<< 2012/07/17 Edit >>>

When the user clicks the "X" button on the form, the only one way to stop the form from closing is to cancel it in the `OnCloseQuery` event.  Then when you are done fading out the form, you close the form.  You'll need a global variable like `FAllowClose` to signal the `OnCloseQuery` event that *you* are close the form instead of the user.  This code is a little more illustrative, and should handle the situation where a user clicks the "X" again while it is fading out.

```
interface

  type TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
    procedure FadeOutTimer(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FAllowClose: Boolean;
  public
  end;

implementation

  procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    FAllowClose := False;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
  begin
    if FAllowClose then // <- is 'False' when user clicks "X"
      Exit;

    CanClose := False; // <- cancels close when user clicks "X"
    FadeOut.Enabled := True;
  end;

  procedure TForm1.FadeOutTimer(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    if Form1.AlphaBlendValue > 0 then
      Form1.AlphaBlendValue := Form1.AlphaBlendValue - 5
    else
    begin
      FadeOut.Enabled := False;
      FAllowClose := True;
      Self.Close;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried according to your solution. But there is another problem. The form is immediately closed without using FadeOutTimer when Mouse pointer is on "X" button. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the proper fade out code for [James L's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500636/delphi-form-closing-by-close-button-on-caption-bar-using-timer/11511886#11511886):

```
procedure Form.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  if FAllowClose then
  begin
    CanClose := True;
    Exit;
  end;

  CanClose := False;
  FadeOut.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure Form.FadeOutOnTimer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MainForm.AlphaBlendValue <= 0 then
  begin
    FadeOut.Enabled := false 
    FAllowClose := True;
    Self.Close
  end
  else 
    MainForm.AlphaBlendValue := MainForm.AlphaBlendValue - 5; 
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is working properly according to my need.